# How can I retrieve files from a MySite profile belonging to former employee?

Tags: my-site

The title kind of speaks for itself.
Someone left the organization, and I need to get into the files of that person on their MySite profile.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Central Admin and change the site collection administrator (Application Management > Change site collection administrators) for their site. Then log in using that user account.

HTH